# replacing elements in a vector of vectors C++

Tags: c++, string, vector

i have a vector of vector that contain just periods
(".") so far and I want to replace certain coordinates on the grid with a symbol that I am taking in from an input file. I am using the replace method but keep getting this error

> " error: no matching function for call to replace(std::basic_string, std::allocator >&, std::basic_string, std::allocator >&, const char [2], const char*)"

I am not sure what that error means. I appreciate any and all help. Thanks in advance

here is my code

```
 #include <vector>
 #include <string>
 #include <fstream>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <algorithm>



using namespace std; 

int main()
{
string locationfilename, filenames,symbol;
int numRows, numCols, startRow, startCol, endRow, endCol, possRow, possCol, id;

cout<< "Enter Locations Filename"<<endl;
cin>>locationfilename;
cout<< "Enter Names Filename"<<endl;
cin>>filenames;

ifstream locations(locationfilename.c_str());
ifstream names(filenames.c_str());

locations>>numRows>>numCols>>startRow>>startCol>>endRow>>endCol;

vector <string> rows(numCols,".");
vector< vector<string> > grid(numRows,rows);


locations>>possRow>>possCol>>symbol>>id;
while(!locations.fail())
{


    if(possRow>numRows || possCol>numCols)
    {
        cout<<id<< " out of bounds-ignoring"<<endl;
    } 
    else
    {
    replace(grid.at(possRow).front(),grid.at(possRow).back(),".",symbol.c_str());
    }

locations>>possRow>>possCol>>symbol>>id;
}

}
```

Comment: `std::replace` takes iterators.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed by Chris, the parameters you passed in `std::replace` are not the correct ones. `std::replace` expects `iterators` for its first two parameters but you are passing `references`.

You can use `begin()` and `end()` to get the iterators:
`std::replace(grid.at(possRow).begin(), grid.at(possRow).end(), ".", symbol.c_str());`